Putting equation and figure side by side with label and caption
I am trying to put a Figure and its equation side by side.
I took the help of How to add figure and equation side by side
But I am not able to put the caption of my figure and label correctly.
Need help.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Figures/gate.png}}}
    \qquad \qquad
    % \captionof{Gate.}        % NEED HELP 
    % \label{fig:gate}         % NEED HELP
    \begin{aligned}
    \text{H}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{array}{rr}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1
    \end{array}\right]
    \end{aligned}
     \label{eq:8}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to make the code minimally compilable. I've also replaced the liine bibtex tag with tags I believe are more suitable. Feel free to revert.

You can also use paracol, although trying to align the two sides is trickier.  OTOH, you can put figures into paracol.

I suggest you place the figure material and the equation material in side-by-side minipage environments. You'll need to choose the relative widths of the two minipages; just make sure that the widths add up to \textwidth.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\usepackage{caption}   % for '\captionof' macro
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{7} % just for this example

\noindent % <-- important
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/gate.png}
\captionof{figure}{Gate} \label{fig:gate}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:8}
\mathrm{H}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} % use '\mathrm', not '\text'
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
     1 &  1 \\
     1 & -1
  \end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


Thank you for help @Mico. To use your solution, I have to use the code from \noindent   ... to ,,, \end{minipage}, but I have to put two enters before putting your code because otherwise the equation and figure tend to overlap with the previous text. I hope, this is your intended solution or you want to make any change in the solution? Presently, I am accepting this as a solution. Thank you for great help.

@mchaudh4 - You're most welcome. In TeX and LaTeX documents, what you call "two enters" will create a paragraph break. Note that my solution also contains "two enters" (and hence one line that's entirely blank) immediately before the line that contains the \noindent instruction.

Thank you @Mico for great help.
